# Директива Disallow в robots.txt для директорий сайта WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo

Является ли безопасным для SEO указывать директиву `Disallow`, в файле robots.txt, для следующих директорий сайта WordPress:

```
/wp-admin/
/wp-includes/
/wp-content/plugins/
/wp-content/themes/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагины и темы в своих папках могут содержать файлы (изображения, например), которые нужны для индексации. Поэтому надо следовать идее стандартного robots.txt, который WordPress создает по умолчанию "на лету":

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```